# How can I foreach this array object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I want to foreach the game name and info and each game must filter as platform_name.

```
$list = (object)[];
$list->egame = 
[
    (object)['platform_name'=>'TT', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game1', 'info'=>'test1'],(object)['game_name'=>'game2', 'info'=>'test2'],(object)['game_name'=>'game3', 'info'=>'test3']]],

    (object)['platform_name'=>'TG', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game4', 'info'=>'test4'],(object)['game_name'=>'game5', 'info'=>'test5']]],

    (object)['platform_name'=>'TBIN', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game6', 'info'=>'test6']]]
];


?>
```

Comment: Why are you casting all your arrays to objects? And http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here You go:

```
<?php
$list = (object)[];
$list->egame = 
[
(object)['platform_name'=>'TT', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game1', 'info'=>'test1'],(object)['game_name'=>'game2', 'info'=>'test2'],(object)['game_name'=>'game3', 'info'=>'test3']]],

(object)['platform_name'=>'TG', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game4', 'info'=>'test4'],(object)['game_name'=>'game5', 'info'=>'test5']]],

(object)['platform_name'=>'TBIN', 'game'=>(object)[(object)['game_name'=>'game6', 'info'=>'test6']]]
];

foreach ( $list->egame as $eg ) {
    foreach ( $eg->game as $game ) {
        echo "game: " . $game->game_name . " info: " . $game->info . "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

**Edit #1** 
Includes platform:

```
foreach ( $list->egame as $eg ) {        
        foreach ( $eg->game as $game ) {
            echo "platform: " . $eg->platform_name . " game: " . $game->game_name . " info: " . $game->info . "<br>";
        }
 }
```

Comment: This is good but can you filter all those game according their platform name? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$list = (object)[];
$list->egame =
[
    (object)['platform_name' => 'TT', 'game' => (object)[(object)['game_name' => 'game1', 'info' => 'test1'], (object)['game_name' => 'game2', 'info' => 'test2'], (object)['game_name' => 'game3', 'info' => 'test3']]],

    (object)['platform_name' => 'TG', 'game' => (object)[(object)['game_name' => 'game4', 'info' => 'test4'], (object)['game_name' => 'game5', 'info' => 'test5']]],

    (object)['platform_name' => 'TBIN', 'game' => (object)[(object)['game_name' => 'game6', 'info' => 'test6']]]
];

$arr = (array)$list->egame;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
foreach ($arr[$i] as $key => $value) {
    $aa = (array)$arr[$i]->game;
    foreach ($aa as $k => $v) {
        echo $aa[$k]->game_name." ".$aa[$k]->info."<br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
}
```